# MIT Kerberos fails to locate TGT in MSLSA cache

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos

I'm struggling with a Windows application which uses MIT Kerberos for authentication.

If a user logs on to Windows with a domain user account, `klist` shows that he gets the expected tickets from the AD, including this one:

```
#1>     Client: jalf @ TESTREALM.COM
        Server: krbtgt/TESTREALM.COM @ TESTREALM.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x40e00000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent
        Start Time: 1/12/2012 9:46:27 (local)
        End Time:   1/12/2012 19:46:27 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/19/2012 9:46:27 (local)
        Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
```

However, when we try to use this ticket in our application, the Kerberos library does not seem to find that one.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
// Open the MSLSA cache
krb5_cc_resolve(kcontext, "MSLSA:", &mslsa_ccache);
// Create a cursor for traversing the cache
krb5_cc_start_seq_get(kcontext, mslsa_ccache, &cursor);
// Check all the credentials in the cache
while (!(code = krb5_cc_next_cred(kcontext, mslsa_ccache, &cursor, &creds)))  {
    // Find the one with the INITIAL flag set
    if ( creds.ticket_flags & TKT_FLG_INITIAL ) {
        // ticket found
        krb5_free_cred_contents(kcontext, &creds);
        break;
    }
    krb5_free_cred_contents(kcontext, &creds);
}

krb5_cc_end_seq_get(kcontext, mslsa_ccache, &cursor);
```

But for whatever reason, we never enter the `// ticket found` part.
Running the code in the debugger, I can see that it finds several of the other tickets shown by `klist`, but for some reason it never finds the one we're interested in.

Can anyone explain this behavior, or how to get around it? Naively, I'd expect the output from `klist` to match the results of iterating over the cache with `krb5_cc_next_cred`.

I'm relatively new to Kerberos, and inherited this code from a coworker who left, so it's possible that I'm missing some vital fundamental piece of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably do not have access to the session key in the LSA. Only SSPI can access. You can try this

> Cause 2: This exception is thrown when using native ticket cache on some Windows platforms. Microsoft has added a new feature in which they no longer export the session keys for Ticket-Granting Tickets (TGTs). As a result, the native TGT obtained on Windows has an "empty" session key and null EType. The effected platforms include: Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000 Server Service Pack 4 (SP4) and Windows XP SP2.
>
> Solution 2: You need to update the Windows registry to disable this new feature. The registry key allowtgtsessionkey should be added--and set correctly--to allow session keys to be sent in the Kerberos Ticket-Granting Ticket.
>
> On the Windows Server 2003 and Windows 2000 SP4, here is the required registry setting:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters
Value Name: allowtgtsessionkey
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0x01  ( default is 0 )
```

> By default, the value is 0; setting it to "0x01" allows a session key to be included in the TGT.
>   Here is the location of the registry setting on Windows XP SP2:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\
Value Name: allowtgtsessionkey
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0x01
```

Java's GSS impl fails here too. This is recommended by Oracle. You may suffer from the same problem with MIT Kerberos.

This change goes in effect after a reboot only.

Comment: +1, Thanks, extremely helpful. That seems to be the issue. I'll need to test it a bit more on monday, and then I'll accept the answer if all goes well. :)

Comment: Seems like it. It's still a bit shaky, but that seems to be a different issue. Sometimes fewer or no tickets seem to in the LSA cache when you log in to the Windows account.

Comment: This is fine. Windows login retrieves the TGT for your domain. Others on request.
Maybe a SSPI-based solution would be better for you. Though this would mean o rewrite your code.

Comment: Yeah, a SSPI approach would be nice, but we're using this through a layer of other libs (XMLRPC-c which in turn calls cURL, which performs Kerberos authentication in some cases), and cURL's SSPI support seems pretty shaky. Further, this is a cross-platform app, and SSPI would obviously only be an option on Windows. I'll try playing around with it a bit more though. Thanks for your help

Comment: cURLs GSS-API is also crap on Unix. After several tricks I was able to compile on Unix but all the steps to make that work. Forget it.

Comment: Turns out the registry key only takes effect after a reboot. Perhaps you should add that to your answer. It tripped me up for a while. But otherwise, this seems to solve the problem